# Casecading dropdownlist is not selected when the button is clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have two drop-down lists. The first drop-down list is populated by the ViewModel. The secondary drop-down list is populated using Ajax (cascading drop-down list). I have this working fine, 
but after I click the button and return to the same page, the second drop-down list is not selected or returns to default. below is my code, Thanks

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PaymentCode, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.country, new { @class = "form-control" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AddNewThirdParty, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.thirdPartyDDL, new { @class = "form-control" })
 <input type="button" value="Add New" name="action:AddNewThirdParty" style="@displayButtonAddThirdParty" onclick="return addnewthirdparty();" />

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#PaymentCode").change(function () {
        $("#AddNewThirdParty").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetInsuranceCompany")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { code: $("#PaymentCode").val() },
            success: function (states) {

                $.each(states, function (i, state) {

                    $("#AddNewThirdParty").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' +
                        state.Text + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
     })
 });
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetInsuranceCompany(string code, string filter)
{
    string codeJP = string.Empty;
    ParamJenisPembayaran paramJP = db.ParamJenisPembayarans.Where(x => x.Code == code).FirstOrDefault();
    if (paramJP != null) codeJP = paramJP.Name;
    var states1 = db.InsuranceCompany_CSFs.Where(x => x.JenisPembayaran == codeJP).ToList();
    List<SelectListItem> listates = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listates.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "select_thrid_party", Value = " " });
    if (states1 != null){
        foreach (var x in states1){
           listates.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.CompanyID + " - " + x.CompanyName, Value = x.CompanyID });
        }
    }
    return Json(new SelectList(listates, "Value", "Text", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
}

 public ActionResult AddNewContractNo(ParamBlacklistPembayaranViewModel model){
   string[] arrContractNumber = string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ContractNumber) ? null : model.ContractNumber.Split(new string[] { ";#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   ViewBag.ContractNumberList = arrContractNumber;
   return View("Create", model);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have used `change()` event, Your second dropdown list will only be populated where there is change in the first dropdown, so you can change your code so that second dropdown can also be populated when page loads.
Try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             populateCascadeList();
             $("#PaymentCode").change(function () {
                 populateCascadeList();
                return false;
             })
         });
}

 function populateCascadeList(){
        $("#AddNewThirdParty").empty();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetInsuranceCompany")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { code: $("#PaymentCode").val() },
                    success: function (states) {

                        $.each(states, function (i, state) {

                            $("#AddNewThirdParty").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' +
                                state.Text + '</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment: it didn't work.  from the code above it is the same as if the first dropdown changes.

Comment: I have edited the answer, placed the populateCascadeList() outside the ready funtion. Also from your end please check when coming back the page $("#PaymentCode").val() should have some valid value.